# $\lim \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = \lim \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=L$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I prove that if $\sum a_n$ is a series with elements non-null and $\lim \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = L$, so $\lim \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| \to L$, then for $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for $n>N$,
$$
\left|\; \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| - L \right| < \epsilon.
$$

But then using a nice cancellation trick, for $n>N$, we have
$$
|a_n|= \dfrac{|a_n|}{|a_{n-1}|} \cdot \dfrac{|a_{n-1}|}{|a_{n-2}|} \cdot \cdots \cdot \dfrac{|a_{N+1}|}{|a_N|} \cdot |a_N|
$$
Notice that all the terms in the product but $|a_n|$ cancel 'diagonally'. But using the inequality above, we have
$$
|a_n|= \dfrac{|a_n|}{|a_{n-1}|} \cdot \dfrac{|a_{n-1}|}{|a_{n-2}|} \cdot \cdots \cdot \dfrac{|a_{N+1}|}{|a_N|} \cdot |a_N| < (L+\epsilon) \cdot (L+\epsilon) \cdots (L+\epsilon) \cdot |a_N|
$$
Then we have proved
$$
|a_n| < (L+\epsilon)^{n-N} |a_N|
$$
Take the $n$th root of both sides to find
$$
\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < (L+\epsilon)^{(n-N)/n} \sqrt[n]{|a_N|}= (L+\epsilon)^{1-N/n} \sqrt[n]{|a_N|}.
$$
Taking the limit,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \leq (L+ \epsilon) \cdot 1= L+ \epsilon
$$
This proves that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \leq L$. But making a small change (can you see which?!) and rerunning the 'same' argument, we find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \geq L$. Therefore, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = L$, as desired.

Comment: Is this small change catch the left part of this second equation $||\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|-L| < \epsilon\Rightarrow L-\epsilon < |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| < L+\epsilon$?

Comment: Seeing the other similar questions now, your answer is much more clear in my opinion.